# Fixed navbar with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I found this cool framework that uses flex as it's grid. http://bulma.io/

I have my header setup as so:

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Left side -->
    <div class="header-left">
      <a class="header-item" href="#">
        <!-- <h1 class="title is-1">VapesForVets</h1> -->
      </a>

    </div>

    <!-- Hamburger menu (on mobile) -->
    <span class="header-toggle">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </span>

    <!-- Right side -->
    <div class="header-right header-menu">
      <span class="header-item is-active">
        <a href="#" class="header-tab is-active">Home</a>
      </span>
      <span class="header-item">
        <a href="#">Why Us?</a>
      </span>
      <span class="header-item">
        <a href="#">FAQs</a>
      </span>
      <span class="header-item">
        <a href="#">Medical</a>
      </span>
      <span class="header-item">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

When I give the header a position:fixed; All the items in the navbar floats to the left.

Comment: Is that any reason that you have to set the position to 'fixed'? Or 'absolute' may do the job?

Comment: @AkiEru I'd like the navbar to follow the screen as I scroll. But even with a position absolute, the elements still end up on the left.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go.

Just added a custom CSS and a jQuery script.

**CSS:**

```
.navbar-fixed {
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var headerHeight = $('header').height();
        if($(window).scrollTop() > headerHeight) {
            $('header.header').addClass('navbar-fixed');
        } else if($(window).scrollTop() < headerHeight) {
            $('header.header').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jLm23LL0/

Comment: What is the benefit of the jQuery part? Your code worked for me without it. Please clarify.

Comment: @AdamSilver, the jQuery part won't fire if you didn't load a jQuery library. The benefits of using jQuery for this part are: 1. You can fire the script in any browsers. 2. The selector and methods save a lot of LOC. 3. Better human readable code isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I am not asking why you used jQuery instead of vanilla JS. My question is what is the benefit of the whole JavaScript part when only the CSS you posted is giving the desired result.

Comment: @AdamSilver Well you can't simply `addClass` and `removeClass` by CSS can you?

Comment: I added the class to header div in HTML!

Comment: @AdamSilver, If the position is fixed, the navbar cannot follow when you scroll down, that's why I need a JavaScript to fix the position once the user scrolls down.